# Refresh browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with images and changing their sizes dynamically from the input I get from the user.

when I change the size of the image first time it doesnot reflect the changes when I click the refresh the page using the browser button the change gets reflected and after that tere is no need to click the refresh button

Please tell how shall I do it so that there is no need to click the refresh button of the browser ,the changes but get reflected at one shot.

Thanks
Ritz

Comment: Hi, you've **a lot** of unregistered accounts: http://stackoverflow.com/users/filter/ritz Please take the little effort to register yourself. Else you'll end up with missing votes/reputation and an unoverviewable question/answer history. You has yet a lot of answers to accept as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is cacheing the image.  One easy way to get around this is to append something to the image URL such as "?v=101", "?v=102", etc. where the number is a version # you track on each image.

E.g.:

- http://mysite.com/image.jpg?v=101
- http://mysite.com/image.jpg?v=102
- http://mysite.com/image.jpg?v=103
- ...

Or:

- http://mysite.com/imagegen.php?name=foo&v=101
- http://mysite.com/imagegen.php?name=foo&v=102
- http://mysite.com/imagegen.php?name=foo&v=103
- ...

You don't have to look at the version number in your code, but its presence on the URL makes the browser think it's a different resource and therefore load it again without having to refresh.